# How do I configure setfont and loadkeys properly?

Tags: linux, fonts, console, locale, keyboard-layout

I'm installing LFS and I'm struggling with [this section](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter07/console.html). My locale is `sv_SE.UTF-8` and I have a Swedish keyboard. So I suppose I should enable unicode and that the keymap is `sv-latin1`:

```
cat > /etc/sysconfig/console << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/sysconfig/console

UNICODE="1"
KEYMAP="sv-latin1"

# End /etc/sysconfig/console
EOF
```

Correct? What I'm struggling with is how to set the font. The book has this example for configuring the German keymap:

```
cat > /etc/sysconfig/console << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/sysconfig/console

KEYMAP="de-latin1"
KEYMAP_CORRECTIONS="euro2"
FONT="lat0-16 -m 8859-15"

# End /etc/sysconfig/console
EOF
```

Since German and Swedish is somewhat similar I suppose I could possibly use the same font, but I don't really understand the difference between lat0-16, lat1-16 and lat2-16. Also how do I know if I'm supposed to use 8859-15 or 8859-1?

> In UTF-8 mode, the kernel uses the application character map for conversion of composed 8-bit key codes in the keymap to UTF-8, and thus the argument of the "-m" parameter should be set to the encoding of the composed key codes in the keymap.

So I guess the -m parameter is dependent on the chosen keymap, but how do I know what application character map my keymap uses?

Finally I also have a question about the font naming: The latin (I suppose that's what lat stands for) fonts have names on the following form: `latX-Y`

Is it correct that X specifies what characters are supported and Y specifies the font size?

Answer (score 3):

The `latin1` stands for Western European languages - i.e. German. `latin2` is for Central European - i.e. Poland, Czech Republic and others. The `lat1-16` stands for `Latin 1 (8859-1)`, font size 16 points. `lat2-16` stands for `Latin 2` (the same with `iso 8859-2`) with height 16 points (pixels).